# Conversion of Degree [0 to 359] to Time [01:00 to 12:59]

Tags: excel, time, formatting

I have a range of degrees, 0 to 360, that I want to translate into time, ranging from 01:00 to 12:59.

Currently i use:

```
=IF(degree<30, "12:"& RIGHT(TEXT(degree/720, "hh:mm"),2),  TEXT(degree/720, "hh:mm"))
```

but this results in a text output.

Is there a custom format string that I can use to do the same thing and be able to further calculate with this time?

---

### Background

When utilizing `degree/720` and `[$-409]hh:mm` u get times ranging from 00:00 to 11:59. I want only the formatting to extend one hour past 12.

---

### UPDATE

I switched back to  `degree/720` and used `[$-409]hh:mm AM/PM` which brings me closer. I still want to get rid of the AM after the time.

Is there an addition to the format string to make AM disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `=degree/720` formula and try `[$-409]hh:mm AM/PM` custom format to display result as 12:10 AM
To realy shift one hour add 1/24 to result

Comment: thats an easy fix, thank you. Now, I want to get rid of the "AM". How do I extend the format string to not show it?

Comment: If you do not post AM / PM how will you know if it is 12:10 at night or 12:10 day?   In the 24-hour format, 00:10 and 12:10 are displayed and 12:10 AM and 12:10 PM are displayed in the 12-hour clock, otherwise confusion is created.

Comment: Another custom format, based on first is: `[<0.041666] [$-en-US]hh:mm AM/PM; [$-en-US]hh:mm`. Now `AM` will be displayed only from 12:00 AM to 12:59 AM

Comment: I dont need to know if the time is AM or PM because I am converting DEGREE to HH:MM (not a real time format). Thanks for the suggestion. I ll give it  a try.

Comment: It worked, but I am not satisfied yet. Anyway, i learned about formatting now, thanks.